# Python regex: insert spaces around characters and letters NOT surrounded by spaces

Tags: python, regex

I have an expression `'Please calculate 1x20 +4 + 5-1 - 2/2 /4'` which I need to convert to this:

```
'Please calculate 1 x 20 + 4 + 5 - 1 - 2 / 2 / 4'
```

The important requirement being that there be only ONE space between the characters and letters of interest. I wrote the following code, which didn't work:

```
import re
message = 'Please calculate 1x20 +4 + 5-1 - 2/2 /4'
message = re.sub(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>x])(?!\s))\s*', " {0} ".format(re.search(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>x])(?!\s))\s*', message).group(0)), message)
message = re.sub(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>+])(?!\s))\s*', " {0} ".format(re.search(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>+])(?!\s))\s*', message).group(0)), message)
message = re.sub(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>-])(?!\s))\s*', " {0} ".format(re.search(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>-])(?!\s))\s*', message).group(0)), message)
message = re.sub(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>/])(?!\s))\s*', " {0} ".format(re.search(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>/])(?!\s))\s*', message).group(0)), message)
message = re.sub(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>*])(?!\s))\s*', " {0} ".format(re.search(r'\s*(?:(?<!\s)([<>*])(?!\s))\s*', message).group(0)), message)
print(message)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: using `x` as multiply sign could conflict with the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using negative lookbehinds and redundantly repeating the same substitution you may just capture a potential surrounding whitespaces `\s*` (zero or more) and make an *ensured* replacement.

```
import re

message = 'Please calculate 1x20 +4 + 5-1 - 2/2 /4'
message = re.sub(r'\s*([<>x+*/-])\s*', ' \\1 ', message)
print(message)
```

- `\s*` - zero or more occurrences of whitespace char
- `[<>x+*/-]` - regex character class, to match only one out of several characters specified

The output:

```
Please calculate 1 x 20 + 4 + 5 - 1 - 2 / 2 / 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Try capturing operators and surrounding them with spaces:

```py
import re
if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = 'Please calculate 1x20 +4 + 5-1 - 2/2 /4'
    fixed = re.sub(r'\s*([+x/*\-])\s*', r' \1 ', q)
    print(fixed)
```

which prints:

```
Please calculate 1 x 20 + 4 + 5 - 1 - 2 / 2 / 4
```